# I want timer function to activate when I click on checkbox (vector standard control) of panel and not when I start simulation

Tags: vector, can-bus, capl, canoe

I made a small script with CAPL in Canoe. I have two System Variables in order to connect panel functionalities with Capl. One that Control whether the signal with name FirstMessage is sent and another that will Regulate the value sent in the FirstMessage.
I made a panel with two elements: CheckBox and TextBox. And the functionality is next, if CheckBox is checked, FirstMessage is sent every 500 ms. And in case it is canceled, it stops sending.
The value to be sent in the ManifestOffer is equal to the one entered in the TextBox.

My code works in a way that it immediately sends cyclic message every 500 ms when I start simulation. But I want that it starts sending it when I click on Checkbox on a panel and that when I uncheck it, timer stops as well. But I got stuck here. Any hints how to do this?

```
variables
{
  msTimer timer_FirstMessage; 
  message FirstMessage msg1;
} 

on start 
{
  setTimer(timer_FirstMessage, 500);
  
  msg1.SignalFirstMessage = $SignalFirstMessage; 
  
  output (msg1);
}

on timer timer_FirstMessage
{ 
  output (msg1);
  
  setTimer(timer_FirstMessage, 500);
}

on sysvar Control::ControlSignalFirstMessage
{
  if (@Control::ControlSignalFirstMessage == 1) 
  {  
    msg1.SignalFirstMessage = @Regulate::RegulateSignalFirstMessage;
    
    write ("Value of SignalFirstMessage is: %d", @Regulate::RegulateSinalFirstMessage);
  
    output (msg1);    
   }          
}
```

Comment: This is happening because you are starting timer in onStart event. Create an event of checkbox checked and there, start the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do (iff. `ControlSignalFirstMessage` is the sysvar bound to your checkbox):

```
variables
{
  msTimer timer_FirstMessage; 
  message FirstMessage msg1;
} 

on start 
{ 
  
}

on timer timer_FirstMessage
{ 
  output (msg1);
  setTimer(timer_FirstMessage, 500);
}

on sysvar Control::ControlSignalFirstMessage
{
  if (@Control::ControlSignalFirstMessage == 1) 
  {  
    msg1.SignalFirstMessage = @Regulate::RegulateSignalFirstMessage;
    write ("Value of SignalFirstMessage is: %d", @Regulate::RegulateSinalFirstMessage);
  
    setTimer(timer_FirstMessage, 500);
    output (msg1);    
  }
  else {
    cancelTimer(timer_FirstMessage);
  }          
}
```

The important differences to your code are:

- The timer is not started in `on start` but only when `ControlSignalFirstMessage` is set to one or when the timer is expired.
- When `ControlSignalFirstMessage` is set to zero, the timer is cancelled, i.e. the automatic sending of your message is stopped.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to send something like initial value so you put different value like $SignalFirstMessage and @Regulate::RegulateSignalFirstMessage
you could program like example:

```
   variables
    {
      msTimer timer_FirstMessage; 
      message FirstMessage msg1;
      int firstdata = 0;
    } 
    
    on start 
    {
 
    }
    
    on timer timer_FirstMessage
    { 
      msg1.SignalFirstMessage = @Regulate::RegulateSignalFirstMessage;
      write ("Value of SignalFirstMessage is: %d", @Regulate::RegulateSinalFirstMessage);
      output (msg1);    
      setTimer(timer_FirstMessage, 500);
    }
    
    on sysvar Control::ControlSignalFirstMessage
    {
      if (@Control::ControlSignalFirstMessage == 1) 
      {  
         if (firstdata == 0) 
           {  
            firstdata =1;
            msg1.SignalFirstMessage = $SignalFirstMessage; 
            output (msg1);
            setTimer(timer_FirstMessage, 500);
           }
       }  
       else
       {
         cancelTimer(timer_FirstMessage);
         firstdata = 0;
       }        
    }
```